# VS Code - can I bind a character sequence to a function key?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code with the Lean language, which supports Unicode characters. The Unicode characters are entered through sequences of ASCII characters. For example, to enter a universal quantifier you enter the five-character sequence `\ a l l TAB`. Is there any way in VS Code to bind that sequence to a function key so that I can say hit `F1` and this is interpreted as entering the ASCII sequence?

Comment: Not sure I really understand your question but you can use the `type` command in a keybinding to insert any text to an editor.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to bind a key in VSCode to a sequence of characters. Here's how to do that in VS Code 1.67.2:

1. Press ctrl+alt+P / cmd+alt+P to open the command palette.
2. Use the command "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts **(JSON)**"
3. Press the "Define Keybinding" button in the bottom right, or press cmd+K cmd+K / ctrl+K ctrl+K, or just type it in.
4. The following works for your case:

```json
{
  "key": "F1",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "\\all\t" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},
```

and for my case

```json
{
  "key": "cmd+.",
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "->" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadOnly"
},
```

The binding will work as soon as you save the file.